# How to set solidity compiler to Mist wallet

Tags: solidity, wallets, mist

I'm trying to create contract in Mist wallet, but it says:

```
Source file requires different compiler version (current compiler is 0.4.24
```

What should I do to write on 0.4.25 in Mist wallet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK, Mist ist bundled with a specific compiler version.

Eventually, your problem is only the `pragma solidity ^0.4.25;` statement in your solidity file. If you do not need a 0.4.25 feature, you could change it to `pragma solidity ^0.4.24;`